# Explicit enumerations of n-tuples of naturals $f:\mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: combinatorics, examples-counterexamples, natural-numbers

For $n=2$ there is a simple and nice enumeration:

$$(i,j) \mapsto f(i,j)=\frac{(i+j)(i+j+1)}{2}+j$$

Obviously, we can use this formula to obtain a general enumeration, for $n=3$, we have:

$$(i,j,k) \mapsto (f(i,j),k) \mapsto f(f(i,j),k)$$

defining $F_n:\mathbb{N}^2\times\mathbb{N}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{N}^n$ as $(a,b,\boldsymbol{p})\mapsto (f(a,b),\boldsymbol{p})$, we obtain enumerations as:

$$H^{(n)}:\mathbb{N}^n\to \mathbb{N}, \qquad H^{(n)}(i_1,\dots,i_n) = (F_{n-1}\circ\dots\circ F_1)(i_1,\dots,i_n)$$

Then, some things came up that surprised me a bit:

- In terms of 3-tuple boxes, $\mathbb{N}^3$ would have a "volume" so I would have expected there to be enumeration that was a cubic polynomial (the volume of a cone and the volume of a pyramid is a cubic polynomial of their maximum dimensions). However, the result is a rather lackluster quartic polynomial. Does this fact have an intuitive explanation?
- What other more elegant ways are there to give enumerations, at least for $\mathbb{N}^3$?

Comment: I visualize your $H_3$ as first "flattening" the first two components out onto a single axis and then treating the third component as a second axis. So it's not "balanced": large $k$ values will appear much earlier in the sequence $H_3^{-1}$ than large $i$ or $j$ values. Increasing $i$ or $j$ requires "skipping ahead" to larger $k$ values at a quadratic rate.

Comment: How about $f(i, j, k) = {   {i+j+1 \choose 2 } + j +k+1 \choose 2 } + k $?

Comment: For a more uniform filling of $n$-dimensional space, I'd try to ensure that a vector with a smaller sum always comes before a vector with a larger sum. Your $H_2=f$ has this property by design.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that "fills $n$-dimensional space in layers" so that the tuples in $\Bbb N^n$ are enumerated in order of their component sum (and each layer is enumerated in sublayers corresponding to values of the sum of the first $n-1$ components, etc.).

The desired function $f_n:\Bbb N^n\to\Bbb N$ (where $\Bbb N$ includes $0$) is:

$$
\begin{align}
f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)&=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{x_1+\dots+x_k+k-1}k\\
&=x_1+\binom{x_1+x_2+1}2+\binom{x_1+x_2+x_3+2}3+\dots
\end{align}
$$

The idea here is that the index of a tuple is just the number of tuples that should precede it in the enumeration, and $\binom{s+k-1}k$ is the number of tuples $(y_1,\dots,y_k)$ with sum less than $s$, by a [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) argument.