Wanted: Closed form for an enumeration of finite lists on $\mathbb{N}$
In their paper "Unambiguously Coded Shifts," (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.01012) Béal et al. give a construction that requires an enumeration of the set of all finite (ordered) lists with entries in an infinite set of words $C$. If we associate each word with its index, we need an enumeration of the set of all finite (ordered) lists with entries in $\mathbb{N}.$ The following does the trick:
Let $\mathbb{N}^*$ be the set of all finite lists with entries in $\mathbb{N}.$  For $x = [a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k] \in \mathbb{N}^*,$ let
$$h(x) = k + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_k$$
be the 'height' of $x.$ Then we sort the lists first by height, then by lexicographic order, so that $x<y$ if $h(x) < h(y)$, or $h(x) = h(y)$ and $x<y$ in lexicographic order.
This is a well-founded order, so we can use it to define an enumeration. Thus the first $10$ elements of $\mathbb{N}^*$ on this ordering are:
$$[\emptyset,~ 0,~ 00,~ 1,~ 000,~ 01,~ 10,~ 2,~ 0000,~ 001,~ \ldots]$$
(I'm joining the lists for readability, i.e. $001 = [0,0,1]$)
Does anyone know of a closed form formula for generating this sequence of lists/strings? I want \begin{align*}
f(0) &= \emptyset, \\
f(1) &= [0], \hspace{2em} \text{ (or the string '0', whatever } \ldots )\\
f(2) &= [0,0], \\
f(3) &= [1], \\
&\ldots
\end{align*}
Something off by one would be fine, too.
Thanks!
Ben Tupper

Related (but not a duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710870

I don't think you mean "closed form formula", but instead an algorithm.

@Somos Why would they mean that? The algorithm is pretty much described in the question.

@NaïmFavier Because "formula" implies producing a number instead of a a finite list of numbers.

Yeah, presumably they want an efficient algorithm (polynomial time in the length of the binary representation of the input value $n$)

My intuition says that since this relates to integer partitions and there is no known closed form for counting those that there similarly isn't a nice formula for this, but I don't know for sure.

It seems more doable if you consider the binary representation of each number:
\begin{align*}
0 = 0 &\mapsto \emptyset \
1 = 1 &\mapsto 0 \
2 = 10 &\mapsto 00 \
3 = 11 &\mapsto 1 \
4 = 100 &\mapsto 000 \
5 = 101 &\mapsto 01 \
6 = 110 &\mapsto 10 \
7 = 111 &\mapsto 2 \
8 = 1000 &\mapsto 0000 \
\end{align*}

I think the solution here basically just involves counting the enumerated items in groups (using stars-and-bars, like in the linked answer) so that, given an index, we can quickly "skip ahead" in the enumeration to the appropriate height value, then the appropriate tuple length, then the appropriate first element, etc. in order to generate the desired tuple.
